# InfoWindow dinamico en angular

Tags: angular, google-maps

estoy desarrollando una web app con angular 11, usando el componente google-map, cuando recorro el array de mis elementos y imprimo el info windows, siempre me pone el detalle del primero, osea, hago clic en el primer marker y en el info window dice Calle:21 altura:111, y al hacer click en otro marker del mapa vuelve a mostrar Calle:21 altura:111, el marker lo creo asi:

```html
<google-map width="100%" height="450px" [center]="center" [zoom]="zoom">

  <map-marker #marker="mapMarker" *ngFor="let unaentidad of listadoEntidades" [position]="unaentidad.Marker" [options]="markerOptions" (mapClick)="openInfo(marker)">
    <map-info-window>
      <p class="font-italic">
        Calle: {{unaentidad.Calle}}<br> Altura: {{unaentidad.Altura}}
      </p>

    </map-info-window>
  </map-marker>

</google-map>
```

Y el info windos lo muestro asi:

```
  openInfo(marker: MapMarker) {  
  this.infoWindow.open(marker)
}
```

Comment: Para que sirve esta asignación: `#marker="mapMarker"`? El problema está ahí, todos los `#marker` apuntan a esa variable.

Comment: No lo se, lo vi así y lo coloqué

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar enviando el objeto a cada infowindow y imprimiendo el valor asi

```
<google-map (mapClick)="openInfo(marker,unapersona)">
```

y en el .ts

```
openInfo(marker: MapMarker, content: Persona) {  
  this.infoWindowCalle =content.Calle;
  this.infoWindowAltura =content.Altura;
   
  this.infoWindow.open(marker)
}
```

y en info window queda asi

```
<map-info-window>
<p class="font-weight-bold">{{infoWindowNombreOrganismoReciclador}}</p>
<p class="font-italic">
Calle: {{infoWindowCalle}}<br>
Altura: {{infoWindowAltura}}<br>
```